# Questions on the Kantorovich-Rubinstein duality

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, markov-process, lipschitz-functions, coupling

Let $\mu,\nu$ be probability measures on a metric space $(E,d)$ endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $$\operatorname W_d(\mu,\nu):=\inf_{\gamma\in\mathcal C(\mu,\:\nu)}\int d\:{\rm d}\gamma,$$ where $\mathcal C(\mu,\nu)$ denotes the set of couplings of $\mu$ and $\nu$.

The Kantorovich-Rubinstein duality states that $$\operatorname W_d(\mu,\nu)=\sup_{\substack{f\::\:E\:\to\:\mathbb R\\|f|_{\operatorname{Lip}(d)}\:\le\:1}}\int f\:{\rm d}(\mu-\nu)\tag1,$$ where $$|f|_{\operatorname{Lip}(d)}:=\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{d(x,y)}\;\;\;\text{for }f:E\to\mathbb R.$$

The "$\ge$" part is almost trivial. Is there an elegant way to prove the other inequality?

In any case, I've got some questions on the statement.

1. Does it matter whether we state it in the given form or if we replace the integral on the right-hand side by its absolute value?
2. If $f:E\to\mathbb R$ satisfies $|f|_{\operatorname{Lip}(d)}<\infty$, then $f$ is clearly continuous and hence Borel measurable. But in order for the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ to be well-defined, it needs to be integrable (or at least quasi-integrable) as well. Is this the case? Clearly, by the reverse triangle inequality, $$\int|f|\:{\rm d}(\mu-\nu)\le|f|_{\operatorname{Lip}(d)}\int d\:{\rm d}\gamma\tag2,$$ where $\gamma$ is any coupling of $\mu$ and $\nu$. So, if we could show that there exists a coupling such that the integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ is finite, we could conclude that $f$ is integrable. Is this the case?
3. In any case, is $(1)$ equivalent to the same statement with requiring $f$ to be bounded as well?